# updating a particular item in a custom list in android

Tags: android, android-listview

In my android app, i used custom list to display a log, which contain a phone no and send status as items.  When i send a sms to a phone no, i updates phone and status as pending.
When the sms delivered, i want to update status as delivered for a particular customer.  how to do this.  Please find code i used for my application

thank you

**myactivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView listview1;
private Vector<Data> datas = null;
private DataAdapter adapter = null; 
private int clickCounter = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    datas = new Vector<Data>();
    adapter = new DataAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, datas);
    listview1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    listview1.setAdapter(adapter);
 }

public void sendSMS() {
    Data data1 = new Data(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "987654321", "Pending");
    datas.add(0, data1);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

**DataAdapter class**

```
public class DataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data>{
Context context;
int layoutResouceId;
Vector<Data> datas = null;

public DataAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Vector<Data> datas){
    super(context, layoutResourceId, datas);
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutResouceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.datas = datas;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    DataHolder holder = null;

    if( row == null ){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResouceId, parent, false);

        holder = new DataHolder();
        holder.phoneno = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.phoneno);
        holder.status = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.status);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (DataHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Data data = datas.get(position);
    holder.txtPhoneno.setText(data.title);
    holder.txtStatus.setText(data.desc);        
    return row;
}

static class DataHolder {
    TextView txtPhoneno;
    TextView txtStatus;
}
}
```

Comment: i think you can find this http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android useful

Comment: there is no problem with sms, i want update as delivered in listview

Comment: for that you need to know whether it is delivered or not

Comment: i think some problem with understanding my question, i just want how to update the status in listview, i successfully implemented sms part.

Comment: I think you need to use some listener which informs you the messages delivered and according to that information you can set the particular information status as delivered